# Schtasks AC Power Issue

Tags: inno-setup, windows-task-scheduler

I am planning to use Inno Setup to schedule a task for my program. This leads me to use schtasks.exe to create the task. The setup must work under XP, so the /XML option is not viable. The program is, when I use schtasks.exe /create ... the task created always has 'Turn off task when not on AC power' or something similar. Is there a way to turn off that option?

Comment: how do you want to schedule , Like on next reboot or on next restart or after some time ...?

Comment: What's wrong on conditional using `/XML` option depending on the user's OS ?

Answer (score 1):

**Added later: NOTE! THIS SOLUTION LOOKS NOT WORKING IF MIGRATED TO ANOTHER WINDOWS XP MACHINE!**

Traditional solution is the following:

- Prepare the task in some Windows XP (I would suggest to make task disabled)
- Save binary file from `%WINDDIR%\Tasks\[TaskName].job` (put your task name instead of [TaskName]). Alternatively you can copy a task from its context menu and paste it into some folder.
- During install in Windows XP:

  - unpack binary file into `%WINDDIR%\Tasks`
  - modify the task using command: `SCHTASKS.exe /Change /TN [TaskName] /ENABLE ...` (put your arguments instead of "...")

Schtasks.exe command line help can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#changing_a_task

Please note that some options are not available in Windows XP. Those options are marked specially.

Answer (score 0):

//try this this may help you,
// this will help you to schedule at specific time, time should be HH:MM(15:20) format 
//This is working fine for me; I am not sure whether this will solve your AC power problem but I am sure that this will be useful to you to schedule properly..

```
 params:='/C schtasks /create /tn "'+TASKNAME+'" /tr "\"'+FileName+'\"" /sc once /st '+timestr;


    Exec('cmd.exe',params, '', SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

//if you want to schedule on next reboot/restart ,you need to modify runonce in registry

cheers..